# Problem with navigation stack

Tags: navigation, move-base

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi all!

I am following this tutorial
http://www.ros.org/wiki/navigation/Tutorials/RobotSetup. I am running
it using stage. While I am running the move base part, I get such
error:

```
[ WARN] [1336375509.493321469, 8.800000000]: The origin for the sensor at (4.75, 4.00, -0.43) is out of map bounds. So, the costmap cannot raytrace for it.
```

Hovever when I am using rviz it seams that it is able to work
correctly sometimes.

Do you know any solution for this issue?

This are my yaml files:

base_local_planner_params.yaml:

TrajectoryPlannerROS:
max_vel_x: 0.45
min_vel_x: 0.1
max_rotational_vel: 1.0
min_in_place_rotational_vel: 0.4

acc_lim_th: 3.2
acc_lim_x: 2.5
acc_lim_y: 2.5

holonomic_robot: true

costmap_common_params.yaml :

obstacle_range: 7.0
raytrace_range: 3.0
footprint: [[-0.7, -0.55], [-0.7, 0.55], [0.7, 0.55], [0.7, -0.55]]
inflation_radius: 0.5
observation_sources: laser_scan_sensor

laser_scan_sensor: {sensor_frame: base_laser, data_type: LaserScan, topic: base_scan, marking: true, clearing: true}

global_costmap_params.yaml :

global_costmap:
global_frame: /map
robot_base_frame: base_link
update_frequency: 5.0
static_map: true

local_costmap_params.yaml:

local_costmap:
global_frame: odom
robot_base_frame: base_link
update_frequency: 2.0
publish_frequency: 5.0
static_map: true
rolling_window: true
width: 36000.0
height: 25000.0
resolution: 0.01

Best regards
Tomasz Kucner

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/33454/problem-with-navigation-stack/) by [tomek](https://answers.ros.org/users/2330/tomek/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2012-05-07

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,
We had that same error message here, and we solved it by adding this line

```
map_type: costmap
```

both to the local_costmap_params.yaml and to the global_costmap_params.yaml.
cheers.

---

Originally posted by [Procópio](https://answers.ros.org/users/1112/proc%C3%B3pio/) with karma: 4402 on 2012-05-07

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1